# Different types together in std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, c++17, variant

Summary of the problem:

Goal: Storing pointer data types(including primary, derived and user-defined) in a vector and freeing the memory safely. So, at `n` index, it may be either float or class(pointer). That's the question.

Additionally, I'm not sure exactly whether `std::variant` is the best option or not. So, I'd be happy if you could also answer that is there any better solution other than`std::variant` such as template or something else? And if the best solution is `std::variant`, how can I free up memory safely/correctly?

Here's my try:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>

namespace _
{
    template<typename ... Args>
    std::string string_format(const std::string& format, Args ... args)
    {
        int size_s = std::snprintf(nullptr, 0, format.c_str(), args ...) + 1;
        auto size = static_cast<size_t>(size_s);
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[size]);
        std::snprintf(buf.get(), size, format.c_str(), args ...);
        return std::string(buf.get(), buf.get() + size - 1);
    }
};// don't mind this

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() {};

    const int var = 10;
};

class Bar
{
public:
    Bar()
    {
    };
   
    const int var = 20;
};

class FUBAR
{
public:
    FUBAR()
    {
    };

    const int var = 30;
};

std::vector<std::variant<Foo*,Bar*,FUBAR*>> list;// Can I use template for this kind of stuff?
inline constexpr int itemCount = 3;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Started";

    Foo* m_f = new Foo();
    Bar* m_b = new Bar();
    FUBAR* m_fb = new FUBAR();

    list.emplace_back(m_f);
    list .emplace_back(m_b);
    list.emplace_back(m_fb);

    std::cout << _::string_format("\nFoo:%i\tBar:%i\tFUBAR:%i\n\n\n\n", m_f->var, m_b->var, m_fb->var);

    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    if (s == "delete")
        for (const auto& p : list)
        {
            const auto index = &p - &list[0];
            const auto curElement = list[index];

            // How to delete them?
            //delete std::get<0>(curElement);
            //delete std::get<1>(curElement);
            //delete std::get<2>(curElement);

        }
    else
        std::cout << "\n free memory!";

    return 0;
}
```

**ADDITIONALLY:**
I exactly need to delete them by accessing them via vector with a method like `std::get` or something else:

```
for (const auto& p : list)
{
    const auto index = &p - &list[0];
    const auto curElement = list[index];

    // How to delete them?
    //delete std::get<0>(curElement);
    //delete std::get<1>(curElement);
    //delete std::get<2>(curElement);

}
```

**Not like deleting local pointer objects right after displaying their value this way:**

```
Foo* m_f = new Foo();
list.emplace_back(m_f);    
std::cout << m_f->var;
delete m_f;
```

Comment: Why not use `std::variant<Foo, Bar, FUBAR>`  instead of `std::variant<Foo *, Bar *, FUBAR *>`?   Then you don't need to worry about managing lifetime of dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @Peter, Because I should return a pointer object.

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev: That's not a good reason. 1) you never *have* to return a pointer; if the user wants a pointer, they can dereference a reference that you return. 2) even if you *have* to return a pointer, *your code* can dereference the result of `get`.

Comment: That's no justification, since all variants of `std::variant::get()` return a reference.  Given a reference, it is trivial to obtain a pointer.   If you must store a pointer, store smart pointers (e.g. `std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Foo> >`).

Comment: Thank you guys for your valuable information and effort. I will try the method you said.